# Apache Storm: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

I installed Apache Storm 1.0 by following [this tutorial](http://opensourceeducation.net/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-strom/) but I am not able to access to the Storm UI from the Internet. Accessing localhost:8080 gives the following error:

```
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:90)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$cluster_configuration.invoke(core.clj:343)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__12106.invoke(core.clj:929)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$make_route$fn__2467.invoke(core.clj:93)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_route$fn__2455.invoke(core.clj:39)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_method$fn__2448.invoke(core.clj:24)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing$fn__2473.invoke(core.clj:106)
at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2570)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:106)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routes$fn__2477.invoke(core.clj:111)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.json$wrap_json_params$fn__11576.invoke(json.clj:56)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__3543.invoke(multipart_params.clj:103)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__4286.invoke(reload.clj:22)
at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$requests_middleware$fn__3770.invoke(helpers.clj:46)
at org.apache.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__12301.invoke(core.clj:1230)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__3474.invoke(keyword_params.clj:27)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__3514.invoke(nested_params.clj:65)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__3445.invoke(params.clj:55)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__3543.invoke(multipart_params.clj:103)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__3729.invoke(flash.clj:14)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.session$wrap_session$fn__3717.invoke(session.clj:43)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.cookies$wrap_cookies$fn__3645.invoke(cookies.clj:160)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$make_service_method$fn__3351.invoke(servlet.clj:127)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$servlet$fn__3355.invoke(servlet.clj:136)
at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet.proxy$javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$ff19274a.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:654)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.handle(AccessLoggingFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.doFilter(AccessLoggingFilter.java:39)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Content of storm.yaml:**

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "/var/storm"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
```

Comment: I resolve the second problem by restarting Zookeeper

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I resolved the two problems by myself.
for the first problem:
I had to restart zookeeper after installing apache storm.

for the second problem:
the problem was not a problem of storm.
the cause of this problem is due to the platform of azure, the 8080 port was closed by default.

So, I thank myself for this effort.
If it were allowed, I will give you (myself) +1M points

Comment: "If it were allowed, I will give you (myself) +1M points" and maybe that's why its not allowed :). Thanks for the answer. It helped me

Comment: Another way to solve this is to remove the /storm node from Zk and restart storm fresh. Maybe the Zk state got corrupted. Make sure you keep a backup in case you need to revert pack.

Comment: I've seen this problem when the storm-local directory which contains the blobstore contents is wiped out, but the ZooKeeper state still references the blobstore objects.  It's an annoyingly obfuscated root cause for the error appearing as it does.  The fix was deleting the ZK nodes related to the absent blobstore elements (e.g., `/storm/blobstore/sometopology*`).

Comment: you can also delete zookeeper data directory once stopped, that is how i was able fix it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and the answer I needed is not here, so here I am.

Before going further, I am using Storm version **2.1.0**. In this version `nimbus.host` has been replaced by the array option `nimbus.seeds`.

In the log is written `Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?`. As `nimbus.seeds` is a mandatory option, to fix the problem I simply added the host IP address as the only element in this list:

```
nimbus.seeds: ["HOST IP"]
```